# GetAsync and PostAsJsonAsync methods passing parameters JsonReaderException error

Tags: asp.net, parameters, client, jsonexception, getasync

I am trying to build a client side of making requests. So i do not know how i pass parameters on GetAsync method. The same problem on PostAsJsonAsync method.

Here is my code:

```
 public static async Task<List<Users>> GetUsers(HttpClient client, Users users, string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api/2.0/users/?id=5&name=name");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            List<Users> listUsers= await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Users>>();
            Console.WriteLine("Returned list.");
            return listUsers;

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
            throw;
        }

    }
```

When i make this request from postman i get the results that i want. The Users class has more variables than the 2 that i request.

GetAsync without parameters works fine. When i run the project i get the error "JsonReaderException: Input string '100.0' is not a valid integer"

Is there another option to pass arguments on url?

Comment: It's true: "Input string '100.0' is not a valid integer". An integer would be "100" (no decimal)

Comment: To be clear, it seems like your API is returning "100.0" for an integer property.

Comment: I know but how is this possible? When i make the request from postman it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the int type of that integer property to float and the problem solved.